# Make checks inside flat list in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using flat list in react native to render the data like this...

```
   <FlatList 
           data={this.state.fetchServices}
           keyExtractor={(a, b) => b.toString()}
           renderItem={({ item }) => (

           <ServiceLayout
           imageUri_banner={{ uri: `${item.images[0].url}` }}
           imageUri_profile={{ uri: `${item.auther_image}` }}
           service_name={`${entities.decode(item.auther_title)}`}
           service_title={`${entities.decode(item.title)}`}
           service_price={`${entities.decode(item.price)}`}
           service_rating={`${entities.decode(item.total_rating)}`}
           />
           )}

           numColumns={2}
         keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
         />
```

In the above code i have to make a check on this..

```
imageUri_banner={{ uri: `${item.images[0].url}` }}
```

but i am not able to make check on the data inside `ServiceLayout` please suggest a way to make check inside flat list

this is my function where i am fetching the data..

```
fetchLatestPostedServices = async () => {
    const Pid = await AsyncStorage.getItem("projectProfileId");
    const response = await fetch(
      CONSTANT.BaseUrl + "services/get_services?listing_type=latest"
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log("This is json");
    if(Array.isArray(json) && json[0] && json[0].type && json[0].type === 'error') {
      this.setState({ fetchServices:[] }); // empty data set 
    } else  {
      this.setState({ fetchServices: json });
    }
  };
```

here is the response i am getting from the server...

```
[
  {
    "favorit": "",
    "service_id": 1159,
    "service_url": "http://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/service/i-will-provide-best-logo-development/",
    "auther_title": "Christian Edwards",
    "auther_image": "http://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/1084_IMG_20190907_084835-1-100x100.jpg",
    "auther_verified": "yes",
    "auther_date": "March 26, 2019",
    "auther_slug": "christian-edwards",
    "service_views": 1,
    "featured_text": "",
    "categories": [
      {
        "category_name": "Music &amp; Audio"
      },
      {
        "category_name": "Programming &amp; Tech"
      }
    ],
    "title": "I will provide Best Logo Development",
    "content": "I will provide Best Logo Development",
    "rating": 0,
    "feedback": 0,
    "total_rating": "0.0",
    "price": "&#36;65.00",
    "delivery_time": "2 Days",
    "response_time": "6 Hours",
    "queu": 0,
    "soled": 0,
    "images": [
      {
        "url": "http://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Screenshot_20190826-215246_Alfa-355x352.jpg"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/IMG-20190826-WA0002-2-355x352.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "reviews": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "favorit": "",
    "service_id": 902,
    "service_url": "http://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/service/i-will-create-fix-customize-your-wordpress-website-20/",
    "auther_title": "Theresa Morris",
    "auther_image": "http://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/3-1-100x100.jpg",
    "auther_verified": "yes",
    "auther_date": "March 26, 2019",
    "auther_slug": "theresa-morris",
    "service_views": 58,
    "featured_text": "Featured",
    "categories": [
      {
        "category_name": "Digital Marketing"
      },
      {
        "category_name": "Fun &amp; Lifestyle"
      },
      {
        "category_name": "Programming &amp; Tech"
      }
    ],
    "title": "I Will Make Professional Excel And Google Sheets",
    "content": "<p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, saeunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Seden utem perspiciatis undesieu.</p>\r\n<p>Accusantium doque laudantium, totam rem aiam eaqueiu ipsa quae ab illoion inventoren veritatisetm quasitea architecto beataea dictaed quia couuntur magni dolores eos quistm ratione vtatem seque nesnt. Neque porro quamest quioremas ipsum quiatem dolor situe sitem amet conctetur adipisci velit sedate quianon.</p>\r\n<h3>Why Should You Hire Me?</h3>\r\n<p>Laborum sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sitems voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aiam eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis etna quasi architecto beatae vitae dictation explicabo. nemo enim ipsam fugit.</p>\r\n<ul>\r\n  <li><span>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia</span></li>\r\n  <li><span>Adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora</span></li>\r\n  <li><span>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto</span></li>\r\n  <li><span>Qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet</span></li>\r\n</ul>\r\n<p>Sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Nequei porrom quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velitn, sed quia nonae numquam eius modi tempora incidunt labore omnis iste natus error sites voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quaem ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia conseq aeuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. </p>",
    "rating": 0,
    "feedback": 0,
    "total_rating": "0.0",
    "price": "&#36;20.00",
    "delivery_time": "3 Days",
    "response_time": "3 Hours",
    "queu": 1,
    "soled": 0,
    "images": [
      {
        "url": "http://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/19-355x352.jpg"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/015-355x352.jpg"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/16-355x352.jpg"
      },
      {
        "url": "http://amentotech.com/projects/api_workreap/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/06-355x352.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "reviews": [

    ]
  }]
```

Comment: What do you mean with "check" the data?

Comment: Could you show me this.state.fetchServices?

Comment: @Auticcat i mean i want to make if conditions on the data

Comment: I don't want to see the process of making, but I want to see the data of status values.

Comment: You mean you want to see the json response comming from server @hongdevelop ??

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: I have edited my question again @hongdevelop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using flatList you can return a function inside the renderItem:

```
       renderItem={({ item }) => {

          //All your checks

           return(
           <ServiceLayout
           imageUri_banner={{ uri: `${item.images[0].url}` }}
           imageUri_profile={{ uri: `${item.auther_image}` }}
           service_name={`${entities.decode(item.auther_title)}`}
           service_title={`${entities.decode(item.title)}`}
           service_price={`${entities.decode(item.price)}`}
           service_rating={`${entities.decode(item.total_rating)}`}
           />
           )}
           numColumns={2}
           keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
           />)
}
```

EDIT.

You can also do inline checks, to see if the image is empty you can do it like:

```
imageUri_banner={{ uri: `${item.images[0].url?item.images[0].url:null}` }}
```

Comment: let suppose i want to check that if image array is empty in this line             imageUri_banner={{ uri: `${item.images[0].url}` }} .  then how to check would be applicable inside ServiceLayout Tag? @Auticcat

Comment: I edited my answer, tell me if there's something unclear, or if you need some explanation

Comment: one more thing i got your point but what if i want to add a custom image reference instead of null then what to do?

Comment: You can just add it, like `"url_to_image"` instead of `null`, or `require("path_to_image")`